# Why do i need private fields when implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, properties

Why do i need private fields when implementing INotifyPropertyChanged? Can i not remove name and just use PersonName string below?

```
private string name;
public string PersonName
      {
          get { return name; }
          set
          {
              name = value;
              // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
              OnPropertyChanged("PersonName");
          }
      }
```

Comment: What would that do?

Comment: So what would you return from the getter? The same getter? Next question: why am I getting a stack-overflow exception?

Comment: Technically you don't need a private field - you can have a calculated property (for example `public int Price => Quantity * Rate;`), then you can call `OnPropertyChanged` from somewhere else (maybe the `Quantity` and `Rate` setters). But you can't use the automatic property (where you just use `{ get; set; }` because that does not let you change what the setter does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need it because you need to store the information somewhere. If you refrence `PersonName` in the getter or setter you would just be calling yourself recursively and would cause a Stack Overflow.

When you do `public string PersonName {get; set;}` the private variable is still there, it is just hidden from you by the compiler. If you use a decompiler like DotPeek you can view the compiler generated code and see the private variables.

Comment: Ah thats where i didnt understand. I thought there was no private variable with public string PersonName; Thanks for clearing that up